# I am trying to add image in a tk window in function error:-image "pyimage4" doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

here is my code:

```
global ad4
global background
global background_l


def getvals():

    print(f"the value of username is {uservalue.get()}")
    print(f"the value of password is {passvalue.get()}")
    if (uservalue.get()).casefold()=="avvh".casefold() and passvalue.get()=="vhjbjh":
       
        b=Tk()
        b.geometry("600x400")

        ad4 = Image.open("My Post.jpg")
        ad4 = ad4.resize((600, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ad4)
        background_l = Label(b,image=background).pack()
        background_l.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

       
       
       
        b.mainloop()
        try:
            label(a).destroy()
        except:
            pass
    else:
        c=Label(a,text="incorrect pass or user name",fg="red").grid()
```

Error:

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\python 3.8.1\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
   File "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/firstfrog/PyGame/new.py", line 274, in getvals
     background_l = Label(b,image=background).pack()
   File "C:\python 3.8.1\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
     Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
   File "C:\python 3.8.1\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
     self.tk.call(
 _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist
```

Comment: This error usually happens when your creating `Tk()` multiple times, for secondary windows replace `Tk()` with `Toplevel()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_tkinter.TclError: image "..." doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668895/tkinter-tclerror-image-doesnt-exist)